# can we implement client side and server side pagination both and choose the one dynamically based on the data size?

Tags: pagination

I am thinking about implementing both client and server side pagination both as each one has pros and cons.
can we implement client side and server side pagination  both and choose the one dynamically based on the data size?

like if the data is below 1000 rows, go for client side but if the rows exceeds the limit, go for server side.

Is it possible to implement such behavior?

Thanks,
Swapnil